# How to resolve Forge Autodesk Digital Twin Platform heatmap color mismatch issue?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk

We are a research group from ETS University in Montreal, Canada, and we are currently facing an issue with the Forge Autodesk Digital Twin Platform (forge-dataviz-iot-reference-app). We are seeking assistance from the community in resolving this issue.

Our model includes various types of data such as temperature, humidity, air quality, etc. The data streams from the Time Series Insight Azure service with Forge APIs on this platform. Although we set the correct data range (min, max) inside the device model and set the gradient colour on the sensor style, unfortunately, we have noticed that the colour shown on the heatmap bar does not match the colour of the geometry heatmap on our model.

We would appreciate any help or advice on how to resolve this issue. While I am a junior in coding, I am willing to make changes to the code or take any other necessary steps to solve the problem myself if needed.

Comment: Please consider adding more details to your question, in this case specifically screenshots, and how you configured the data ranges.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest that you checkout https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-iot-extensions-demo which is a sample app similar to `forge-dataviz-iot-reference-app` but it's significantly easier.